# UnionAggregate (geometry Data Type)

Tags: sql-server, spatial

Does SQL Server 2008 R2 suport UnionAggregate (geometry Data Type) method?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the Friendly Manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The BOL page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933960%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for methods on geometry instances doesn't list a method by that name. But there's STUnion, which I've used in the past.